# Apt states system packages and other installed packages as orphaned and to be autoremoved

Tags: apt, gnome

I was installing a package recently, and i found that apt was about to autoremove the following packages. Luckily I have had this experience before and I aborted the process and installed the removed packages again, but every time i run apt it tries to remove them again. Please help.

```
acpi-support acpid alsa-utils anydesk apport-gtk avahi-utils binfmt-support blt bluez bluez-obexd breeze caps catdoc clipit curl dc dctrl-tools dkms dvdauthor dvgrab ed
  ffmpeg frei0r-plugins ftp gamemode gdb gedit genisoimage ghostscript-x gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-font-viewer gnome-logs gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons gnome-system-monitor gnome-themes-extra gnome-tweaks
  google-chrome-stable gstreamer1.0-packagekit gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs-fuse hdparm hplip info ippusbxd iputils-tracepath irqbalance jackd2-firewire
  kaccounts-providers kde-style-breeze kded5 kdenlive kerneloops kinit kpeople-vcard kwin-style-breeze liba52-0.7.4 libabw-0.1-1 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libao4 libaribb24-0
  libatopology2 libavresample4 libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-indicator3-7 libbabeltrace1 libbdplus0 libbluetooth3 libbrlapi0.7 libcddb2 libconfig++9v5 libcupsimage2
  libdca0 libdvbpsi10 libdw1 libe-book-0.1-1 libepub0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libespeak-ng1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libfaad2 libfdk-aac1 libffado2 libgamemode0 libgamemodeauto0 libgavl1
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libglu1-mesa libglvnd-dev libgnome-menu-3-0 libgtkglext1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libhandy-0.0-0 libiw-dev libiw30 libjson-xs-perl libkate1 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private7 libkf5contacts5 libkf5filemetadata-bin
  libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-plugins libkf5style5 liblcms2-utils liblivemedia77 liblqr-1-0 liblua5.2-0 libluajit-5.1-2 libmad0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmatroska6v5 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmessaging-menu0 libminizip1 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4 libmwaw-0.3-3
  libndp0 libodbc1 libodfgen-0.1-1 libopengl-dev libopengl0 libopenmpt-modplug1 libpangox-1.0-0 libpcaudio0 libpcre16-3 libpcre2-32-0 libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix2
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libplacebo7 libpoppler-qt5-1 libprotobuf-lite17 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libpulse-dev libqt5charts5 libqt5concurrent5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5test5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libquicktime2 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-math libreoffice-writer libresid-builder0c2a
  librttr-core0.9.6 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane-hpaio libsdl-image1.2 libselinux1-dev libsidplay2
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsonic0 libspatialaudio0 libspeechd2 libsrt1 libssh2-1 libteamdctl0 libtepl-4-0 libtorrent-rasterbar10 libupnp13 libva-wayland2 libwmf0.2-7
  libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxatracker2 libxcb-xtest0 libxdo3 libxml++2.6-2v5 libxres1 libzip5 linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic
  linux-headers-generic lshw ltrace melt mscompress mtools mtr-tiny nano nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share network-manager obs-studio openjdk-8-jre-headless orca
  paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter pcmciautils phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc ppp printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-m2300w
  printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-splix pulseaudio-module-gsettings pulseaudio-module-jack pulseaudio-module-zeroconf python-gi
  python3-bcrypt python3-brlapi python3-crypto python3-gi-cairo python3-ldb python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-samba python3-tdb python3-tk qbittorrent
  qjackctl qml-module-org-kde-newstuff recordmydesktop rsync rygel samba-common-bin signon-plugin-oauth2 speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins
  speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng stacer strace swh-plugins tap-plugins tcpdump telnet thunderbird-gnome-support time tk8.6-blt2.5 v4l2loopback-dkms vlc-plugin-base
  vlc-plugin-video-output whoopsie wireless-tools xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdotool xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yaru-theme-gtk zip zoom
```

As you can see most of the packages were installed by me and some are ubuntu stock and some are actively used packages.

Everytime I try to install something with apt, the above packages are REMOVED. I don't want that to happen since these are basic packages and my whole environment may collapse in case these are removed.

Comment: I would run `sudo apt update` and read the messages, assuming you know your release (you didn't provide it), you'll hopefully recognize messages that shouldn't belong (ie. sources that are inappropriate for your system which possibly led to this issue).  Your pasted messages do not include package info, nor do we know your release so we currently cannot help, but it's likely mistaken sources/packages added to your system that conflict with your *unstated* release of *unstated* OS.

Comment: I also noticed that based on the packages I install the autoremove also changes ..... this only happens for wine and lmms

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

This kind of mass-removal is most common when folks build up their system from a minimal install. Your whole system is hanging on the *-desktop metpackage. When you make some change that removes the metapackage, poof!

Folks who installed using the normal Desktop installer get additional protection from this kind of mass-removal: The installer changes the apt-marking of the packages in the base install.